# Docker problem to connect nginx/php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx

I'm trying to setup a docker for some PHP projects for local environment. I have created `docker-compose` file:

```
############
## This is the LOCAL docker-compose. local is not in the file to make it default,
## easy for development.
############
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/images/nginx
    image: project/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - project_volume:/var/www/vhosts/abboom
    networks:
      project:
        aliases:
          - project.local.net
    environment:
       - VIRTUAL_HOST=project.local.net
  php:
    build: ./docker/images/php
    image: project/php:latest
    ports:
      - "7778:7778"
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - project_volume:/var/www/vhosts/project
    networks:
      - project
  workspace:
    build: ./docker/images/workspace
    image: project/workspace:latest
    volumes:
      - project_volume:/var/www/vhosts/project
    working_dir: /var/www/vhosts/project
    networks:
      - project
  redis_disk:
    build: ./docker/images/redis_disk
    image: project/redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - project
  mysql:
    image: project/mysql:latest
    build: ./docker/images/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - project
    ports:
      - "33066:3306"
networks:
  project:
    name: project

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
  project_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      device: "$PWD/project"
      o: bind
```

also probably I need to share the nginx virtual host for a project (I took this virtual host config from the staging server, maybe it require some more changes?)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name project.local.net;
    root         /var/www/vhosts/project/public;

    index index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   400 404 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
    }

    location ~ /(assets/|content/|images/|stylesheets/|javascripts/|vendor/|fonts/|favicon.ico) {
    root          /var/www/vhosts/project/public;
    }

    location / {
            root           /var/www/vhosts/project/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

So the issue is that I'm getting the error `Uncaught PDOException: could not find a driver in` when I'm trying to access the site from a browser, but when I, for example, running migration from `worksapce` or `php` container all is working correctly.

I'm assuming that for some reason `nginx` container is not linked with `php` container and trying to find the pdo driver inside of the `nginx` container instead of looking it in the `PHP`? But it also sounds like not correct, as it starts processing php scripts and stacking only on the pdo, so it connected to the `php` container, so I'm not sure where to look for a problem

Previously I have made docker setup for many projects but they was written with PHP frameworks like `Laravel`, `Symfony` , but this one is a handwritten project and maybe it requires some additional changes?

**Updated**

Here is a php Docker file:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

LABEL maintainer="Vincent Composieux <vincent.composieux@gmail.com>"

RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
    postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --update \
    php7-common \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-apcu \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-gd \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-json \
    php7-intl \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-phar \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-session \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-bcmath\
    php7-intl \
    php-fileinfo \
    php7-redis \
    php-gd \
    make \
    curl \
    nano \
    g++ \
    icu-dev \
    libxslt \
    libxslt-dev



RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl  && docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install xsl

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    curl --insecure https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

ADD php.ini /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/
ADD php.ini /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
ADD php.ini /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
ADD xdebug.ini  /etc/php7/conf.d/

ADD www.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/


RUN   sed -i "s|memory_limit = 128M|memory_limit = 512M |g" /etc/php7/php.ini
RUN   sed -i "s|upload_max_file_size = 2M|upload_max_file_size = 1024M |g" /etc/php7/php.ini
RUN   sed -i "s|post_max_size = 8M|post_max_size = 1024M |g" /etc/php7/php.ini
RUN   sed -i "s|max_execution_time = 30|max_execution_time = 600 |g" /etc/php7/php.ini

CMD ["php-fpm7", "-F"]

WORKDIR /var/www/vhosts/project
EXPOSE 9000
```

also `php -m` showing `pdo_mysql` in the list of enabled extensions

Comment: Or maybe the issue is that `php-fpm` does not see pdo extension, but cli does see?

Comment: as I wrote in the original question it. working from CLI but not from fpm, and both database migration script and `index.php` using the same bootstrap logic, I add such a debug `var_dump(extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'));die;` and in CLI it returns `true` but from browser `false`. So looks like extension is not enabled for fpm for sore reason

Comment: also, I found that CLI (`php -i | grep php.ini`) using `php.ini` file from `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`, but FPM (`var_dump(phpinfo());die;`) from `/etc/php7/php.ini`, maybe thats a case

Answer (score 0):

I made it, so if in docker file I have only `RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql` it's working for CLI, if I have only `RUN apk add --update php7-pdo_mysql` it's working for fpm but not for cli, so I added both and it working for for cli and fpm. But it's weird as I'm using boiler plait docker confids I have used already many times, and first time faced that issue...